# Laravel 8 update issue, it updates all records and not only one

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to update two tables on a PUT request in a API using Laravel 8, the first update runs fine but the second is updating all the records in the table, can you please point me in the right direction here?

```
  $utility_uuid = $request->input('utility_uuid');

  $utility = Utility::where('utility_uuid', $utility_uuid)->first();
  
  $utility->utility_type = $request->input('utility_type');
  $utility->provider = $request->input('provider');
  $utility->account = $request->input('account');
  $utility->meter = $request->input('meter');
  
  $utility->update(); # This updates fine
  
  $connection = Connection::where('utility_uuid', $utility_uuid)->first();
  
  $connection->connection_status = $request->input('connection_status');
  $connection->deposit_information = $request->input('deposit_information');

  $connection->update(); # This updates all records in table Connections?
```

Comment: 1) [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates): "*The update method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated*".  You should be using `->save()` here. I don't think that explains your problem but it is worth fixing and checking.  2) What debugging have you tried?  Eg have you checked what `$utility_uuid` is?  What does `dd($connection)` show?  How about dumping the SQL that actually runs?

Comment: dd($connection) was returning a select all query, =|, just fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround but was hoping to get this running using the Eloquent ORM

If if change this to a DB query it works fine:

```php
DB::table('connections')
->where('utility_uuid', $utility_uuid)
->update([
 'connection_status' => $request->input('connection_status'),
 'deposit_information' => $request->input('deposit_information'),
]);
```

Per @DontPanic suggestion, after a few trial and error, added the required array as stated in the documentation and got this running fine now:

```php
$connection->where('utility_uuid', $utility_uuid)
->update([  
  'deposit_information' => $request->input('deposit_information'),
  'remarks' => $request->input('remarks'),
]);
```